# Make from *either* source file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have this make rule:

```
dist/node/%.js: src/%.node.js yarn.lock .babelrc | $(NODE_DIST_DIRS)
    $(BIN)/babel $< -o $@
```

It works fine when my source file ends with `.node.js`. e.g.,

```
$ make dist/node/fs.js
mkdir -p dist/node/
node_modules/.bin/babel src/fs.node.js -o dist/node/fs.js
```

However, I want to compile `dist/node/fs.js` from *either* `src/fs.node.js` or `src/fs.js`, whichever exists.

The reason for this is that I have some shared files with just the `.js` extension (work in both browser and node), and then more specific files with the `.node.js` extension. If there's a more specific version, I want to use that.

I don't know how to do conditional dependencies in combination with `%`. Is this possible? Can I give precedence to dependencies and take the best match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that in a single rule.  You'll have to write two rules with different prerequisites but otherwise the same:

```
dist/node/%.js: src/%.node.js yarn.lock .babelrc | $(NODE_DIST_DIRS)
        $(BIN)/babel $< -o $@

dist/node/%.js: src/%.js yarn.lock .babelrc | $(NODE_DIST_DIRS)
        $(BIN)/babel $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could try using a [double-colon rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Double_002dColon.html), but those cannot be pattern rules.

As an alternative, consider [generating and including a makefile containing just those dependencies](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html).